# Oracle SQL convert HEX to char

Tags: sql, oracle, hex

i am trying to convert a hexadecimal to character in Oracle ideally something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) for Microsoft SQL Server

```
select xx('0A') from dual;
```

where `0A` is hexadecimal for newline in Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or

```
SELECT ASCIISTR(CHR(TO_NUMBER('0A','xx'))) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (<string>, <src_char_set>) FROM DUAL;
```

For example,

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('0A', 'AL32UTF8') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this on Oracle9i? UTL_I18N requires 10g

Comment: Try if this works -> SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('0A') FROM DUAL;

Comment: Looks good, but UTL_I18N also allows you to specify tyhe encoding as UTF-8; which apoarrently I need. Thank you Bharathi.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [HEXTORAW](http://psoug.org/definition/HEXTORAW.htm) converion function and check the [reference](http://psoug.org/reference/convert_func.html) for more conversion funcitons